# Rangy: How to createCssClassApplier with dynamic elementProperties

Tags: javascript, jquery, rangy

my code:

```
var cssApplier;
        window.onload = function () {
            rangy.init();
            cssApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("highlight", {
                ignoreWhiteSpace: true,
                elementTagName: "span",
                elementProperties: {
                    id: new Date()
                }
            })
        };
```

But when i call

```
cssApplier.applyToSelection();
```

It always render a span with the same id property, How can i set id property dynamic?

Comment: `Math.floor( new Date().getTime() * Math.random())`

Comment: The same: new Date().getTime() but rangy not update property every time call applyToSelection() function :(

Answer (score 3):

`new Date()` is evaluated just once at the point at which you call `rangy.createCssClassApplier()`. The only way you could generate a new `id` for each element created would be if Rangy provided means of specifying a callback every time it creates a new element, which it currently does not. However, this is something I've been considering adding anyway. I've added an issue to the Rangy issue tracker:

https://github.com/timdown/rangy/issues/143

**UPDATE**

You can do this now in Rangy 1.3 by passing `onElementCreate` in the options object:

```
var id = 0;
var applier = rangy.createApplier("someClass", {
    onElementCreate: function(el) {
        el.id = "rangySpan_" + (id++);
    }
});
```